# CoffeeScript IDE for Windows - tried Titanium Studio and RubyMine

Tags: javascript, ide, titanium, coffeescript, rubymine

I'm trying to find a good way to work on CoffeeScript on Windows and be able to process these files quickly to JavaScript in the IDE.

RubyMine - if I just open a .coffee file in RubyMine this seems to work. But I see no button or menu option to convert to JavaScript.

Titanium Studio - in this IDE there is a Menu option to do the conversion - but when used it seems to call out to gitbash on my machine. At least that is what shows up in the console in the IDE.

So I'd like to get one or both of these to work on Windows... or get an alternate suggestion for a good CoffeeScript IDE with the translation process built-in.

Answer (score 4):

RubyMine relies on Rails framework for CoffeeScript to JavaScript compilation at the moment.

Cutting edge CoffeeScript support is available in PhpStorm/WebStorm products, in the EAP versions to be released by the end of 2011. You can download and try them at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP.

[Watch the issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-5943) for progress.

Latest version has an action to compile CoffeeScript, but it just displays a window with the result without writing any files (`Help` | `Find Action` | **Compile Coffeescript File**, or bind it to keyboard shortcut in `Settings` | `Keymap`).

Note that it's still work in progress, more features will be available soon. At the moment you can probably set up compilation using command line external tools.

Comment: +1 - this is awesome. I do prefer to just use the Compile CoffeScript from the context menu. Please keep that. Will there be support added for a "Compile and Save" menu option that just replaces the .js file extension with .coffee ?