# Java project with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, coffeescript

I'm trying to introduce coffeescript to the team on a Java project. I think the problem we're facing right now it's that when we write a Coffeescript we have to go compile it down to Javascript which is a bit daunting and cumbersome. And the client has already invested in IntelliJ Ultimate Edition already. Is there a nice tool or plugin in IntelliJ to convert Coffeescript to Javascript easily?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a plugin available here:

http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=6313 and
http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=4701

Comment: Does this plugin will convert Coffeescript to Javascript for me automatically. I have just come across wro4j which will compile coffeescript when I run the server up. I'm not sure if it's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [my reply to similar question on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173031/coffeescript-ide-for-windows-tried-titanium-studio-and-rubymine/8174246#8174246).

At the moment you should use command line or some other third-party tools for compilation.