# Compile .coffee files in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, webstorm

Is it possible to compile the .coffee files I am editing from WebStorm?

(Without leaving the IDE, something similar to Mindscape's Web Workbench for Visual Studio.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoffeeScript IDE for Windows - tried Titanium Studio and RubyMine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173031/coffeescript-ide-for-windows-tried-titanium-studio-and-rubymine)

Comment: The above link contains the answer, however the title and the question do not relate to this question..

Comment: CoffeeScript compiler setup for WebStorm
http://zsitro.com/coffeescript-compiler-setup-for-webstorm/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Automatic compilation is available since 6.0 version with the File Watchers feature:

- [File Watchers in WebStorm/PhpStorm 6 (a.k.a. “Background Tasks”)](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/file-watchers-in-webstormphpstorm-6-a-k-a-background-tasks/)

---

Though you can find the same answer in the question that is suggested as a duplicate, I'll post it here again with minor corrections for the recent WebStorm version:

Latest WebStorm version has an action to compile CoffeeScript, but it just displays a window with the result without writing any files (`Help` | `Find Action` | **Preview Compiled Coffeescript File**, or bind it to keyboard shortcut in `Settings` | `Keymap`).

The same action is available in the editor context menu.

Comment: I am surprised that there isn't an auto compile feature to the IDE